# unit test using gtest 1.6 : how to check what is printed out?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googletest

How do i check a void function that print out sth to the command line?

For example:

```
void printFoo() {
                 cout << "Successful" < endl;
             }
```

and then in the test.cpp  i put this  test case:

```
TEST(test_printFoo, printFoo) {

    //what do i write here??

}
```

please explain clearly as i'm new to unit testing and gtest. Thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You will have to change your function to make it testable. The easiest way to do this is to pass in an ostream ( which cout inherits ) to the function, and use a string stream ( also inherits ostream ) in your unit tests.

```
void printFoo( std::ostream &os ) 
{
  os << "Successful" << endl;
}

TEST(test_printFoo, printFoo) 
{
  std::ostringstream output;

  printFoo( output );

  // Not that familiar with gtest, but I think this is how you test they are 
  // equal. Not sure if it will work with stringstream.
  EXPECT_EQ( output, "Successful" );

  // For reference, this is the equivalent assert in mstest
  // Assert::IsTrue( output == "Successful" );
}
```

Comment: You probably mean ``os << "Successful" < endl;``

Comment: output in EXPECT_EQ needs to call `.str()` to compare to the string "Successful" e.g. `EXPECT_EQ( output.str(), "Successful" );`