# Unit test in C++ How to access my result in source code that just showed by printf

Tags: c++, unit-testing

I am writing a unit test in C++. My final results in the source code designed to show by

```
printf("%d\n", ResultA);
```

and there is no return `ResultA`.

I have to mention that the `ResultA` simply comes after a comparison of 3 values so I do not have any function that return me `ResultA`. Something like this:

```
if a<b  --> ResultA= 1
if a>b  --> ResultA= 2
```

I wonder how in my unit test I can access the ResultA? because I need to have that value and see if it is reported correctly.

Comment: No idea what you are asking. You access the value to pass it to `printf` and perform comparisons. So what is the problem?

Comment: In Unit Test I need to access this value but in my code  I do not return the value. is there any way to access ResultA through printf in unit test?

Comment: I don't know whether I get you correctly. Maybe this is the similar problem. Take a look at it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18908923/unit-test-using-gtest-1-6-how-to-check-what-is-printed-out

Comment: There are several options, but all involve some work. Either change your code to output to a string, or output the value and test the value (for most cases, `printf` does what it should and is part of the library that comes with the compiler, so you don't need to test that `printf` works). Or you could write some code to capture the output from `stdout` via for example a pipe, and then compare the output from `stdout` - although I would save that for the "whole program test" rather than the unit-test, as it's typically the combination of printf output that goes wrong, not the individual ones.

Answer (score 1):

You make a function that produces the value and write a unit test for it.

```
int MakeResultA()
{
    return 5;
}

void SomeFunction()
{
    int resultA = MakeResultA();
    printf("%d\n", resultA);
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(MakeResultA)
{
    BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL(MakeResultA, 5);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to refactor your code so that you can access the result as a return value, as suggested by Don, that is definitely the best solution. The answer I am presenting here is somewhat of a nasty hack and it is not for the faint hearted.

It is possible to define your own version of printf, which will capture the value of the argument(s) you want to check.

For example, if the code you want to test looks like this:

```
//code_to_test.cpp
#include <cstdio>

void myFunction() {
        printf("The result is: %d\n", 42);
}
```

then an example test harness could look like this:

```
// main.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdarg>

using namespace std;

void myFunction();

int captured;

int printf(const char *format, ...) {
        va_list ap;

        va_start(ap, format);
        captured = va_arg(ap, int);
        va_end(ap);

        cout << "Captured :" << captured << endl;

        return 1;
}


int main() {
        myFunction();
        return 0;
}
```

Compile like this:

```
g++ -c code_to_test.cpp
g++ main.cpp code_to_test.o
```

The output you get is this:

```
$ ./a.out
Captured :42
```

It works because the linker sees there is a printf function defined in your test harness, and uses that instead of the one in the standard C library.

Needless to say, this approach is fraught with dangers. You need to cater for all combinations of arguments which all calls to printf may make in the code under test, and of course you can't actually use printf anywhere to print anything out.

But if you are in a really tight corner, and considering this is only for a unit test, not production code, I guess it might get you out of trouble.